# Automatically create attribute object in perl Moose without using BUILDARGS

Tags: perl, moose

I want to create complete object hierarchy from hashref WITHOUT using BUILDARGS. Is there a possible and easy way to do it?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;
{
    package Obj1;

    use v5.14;
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Moose;

    has 'backend' => (
        is          => 'ro',
        isa         => 'Obj2',
        required    => 1,
    );

    no Moose;
    __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

    1;
}
{
    package Obj2;

    use v5.14;
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Moose;

    has 'flag' => (
        is          => 'ro',
        isa         => 'Bool',
        required    => 1,
    );

    no Moose;
    __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

    1;
}

my $data = {
    backend => {
        flag => 1
    }
};

my $s = Obj1->new($data);
say $s->backend->flag;
```

So far I have been using BUILDARGS, but I suppose this could be somewhat automated, right? Here is simple example, in my code there is deeper hierarchy and it would be really nice if I could stop writing BUILDARGS for each class.

Answer (score 3):

You could use type coercion.

1. Define the type and coercion somewhere (the Moose Best Practices recommend putting all of your type definitions in a single module):

   ```
   package My::Types;
   use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
   class_type 'Obj2Class', { class => 'Obj2' };
   coerce 'Obj2Class', from 'HashRef', via { Obj2->new($_) };
   ```
2. Modify `backend` with the new type definition and make it coercible:

   ```
   use My::Types;
   has backend => (
       is       => 'ro',
       isa      => 'Obj2Class',
       coerce   => 1,
       required => 1,
   );
   ```

And that should be it.